# bootstrap 3: column re-order on breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i was doing an interface with column ordering in Bootstrap 3 and i got this problem.

I have 2 columns by this:

LG: ColumnA ColumnB

MD: ColumnA 
       ColumnB

but i need this:

LG: ColumnA ColumnB

MD: ColumnB 
       ColumnA

How i can reordening on MD resolution the divs? im trying with pull and push and no getting luck :(

Thanks in advance...

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-push-0 col-lg-9">
        ColumnA
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-pull-0 col-lg-3">
        ColumnB
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete - `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` is not closed. Also, if possible please give us an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a suggestion but maybe not the perfect solution but you can use it if you only need to reorder these two columns:

1. remove from your code **( push )** and **( pull )** that you used.
2. make another copy of your code under the original one.
3. now the important thing is to use [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) that Bootstrap offer.
4. all you need to do is to use this two classes **( .visible-xx )** and **( .hidden-xx )**
   and *(xx : xs, sm, md, lg)*.
5. by using them with your original code will make the Column you want visible or hidden at the resolution you need.

**e.g:**

```
 LG: ColumnA -- .visible-xx or .hidden-xx  ( at the needed resolution )
     ColumnB -- .visible-xx or .hidden-xx  ( at the needed resolution )
```

then the needed code using this two classes can also be like this :

```
MD: ColumnB  -- .visible-xx or .hidden-xx  ( at the needed resolution )
    ColumnA  -- .visible-xx or .hidden-xx  ( at the needed resolution )
```

** remember not to forget to change the order of your code in the copy like :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="">
      ColumnB
   </div>

   <div class="">
      ColumnA
   </div>
```

### **Important:**

It's better to use the modifier classes `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` whenever possible, refer to the [column ordering section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) in the Bootstrap documentation, if it's not working you can use the other way.

So you can try this first:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-push-3">
        Column B will be here
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">
        Column A will be here
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: It sounds like this suggests that you should have duplicate content on your page. Even if that content is hidden, it is still indexed by Google. If this page isn't intended as a crawlable page, then this solution works (although sloppy), but it is not the correct way of handling this. Asotos' answer is the proper solution on how to handle this within a pure CSS/Bootstrap solution.

Comment: Use push-pull instead to avoid the extra markup as in @Asotos answer

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 3 uses a **mobile-first** approach, which means fixing things like the grid for smaller screens first, and then moving on to apply styles for the desktop.

If it's ok **semantically** and SEO-wise (same thing IMO) change the mark-up to reflect the desired order for your columns in *Extra Small*, *Small* and *Medium* devices, and **then** apply `col-lg-push-*` and `col-lg-pull-*` to re-order your columns for *large* devices.

Here is the code for your case:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-push-3">
        ColumnB
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">
        ColumnA
    </div>
</div>
```

If it doesn't make sense semantically to change your mark-up, I'm afraid `col-*-push-*` and `col-*-pull-*` won't help, and probably some hacking is due...

Comment: The "mobile first" part really helped me to finally understand the 'push' and 'pull' styles. I was starting with my DIVs ordered based a desktop view, and then trying to re-order for the mobile view. Once I did the opposite, it all makes sense.

Comment: This "mobile first" approach is really a limitation of CSS. This limitation is addressed by the Flexbox specification (which is finally well supported by all major browsers). Presentation is supposed to be decoupled from the structure of an html document, so the mobile-first structure I suggested, should only be a temporary inconvenience. At some point Bootstrap and similar frameworks or grids, will let us structure our page however we want/need, and still be able to shift columns or boxes around using media queries...